# Android UI editor

Tags: java, android, eclipse, flash, air

I know there's air flash for android but for industrial applications ActionScript isn't very efficient, so I'm wondering if there's a way to make UI using flash and then add logic into using ADT (A: android) with java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly, but if you want to load and play an swf-file you should use a WebView
Something like this should work:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/c.swf");
```